# what is the best way to use map function on elements of list in list of lists

Tags: scala

I want to use map function on elements of each list in list[list[String]] and was not sure the best way to do it.

I have the following for example:

```
val x = List(List("james"), List("mike"))
```

I want append Hi to elements of each lists using map:

```
 x.map(x => x.map(x=>"hi " + x))
```

So my question is:

Is this the best way to do the above???

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the way to do it. You could make it very slightly shorter: `x.map(_.map("hi " + _))`

Comment: @JoeK You should post that as an answer.

Comment: i'd avoid repeating variable names e.g. `x`, `x` and `x` might get confusing

Comment: @ joe thanks for the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the use of any variable name and use only default one

```
names.map(_.map("Hi "+_))
```

Comment: [Recommended whitespace around infix operators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation)